# Godot 3D coordinate system independent movement

Tags: coordinates, godot, gdscript, godot4

I've seen a lot of examples of 3d fps movement. All of them use global X and Z global coordinates to walk/sprint and Y coordinate for falling/jumping. I have next question: can i create local coordinate system which will use root object coordinates in the same way but relative to global? E.g. if i will rotate root object by 90 degrees around Z axis my controller will use Z and Y axis for walk/sprint and X axis for falling/jumping?

Comment: Unless you are modifying `global_transform` property you will be transforming your objects in parent `Node3D`'s local coordinate system.

Comment: but its not. I have controller rotated by -90 degrees by Z axis and it falls by Y anyway. Found global_transform.basis.xform solution for Godot3

Comment: If this is a `RigidBody3D`, It will fall towards the gravity vector specified in project settings. If it is a `KinematicBody3D` (godot3.x) or `CharacterBody3D` (godot4.x) you will be implementing gravity effect yourself, if you fall towards -y of the local coordinate system, you will experience what you are experiencing right now. You can avoid this by not making your character a child node of the "level" or the "world" you are rotating. Otherwise you will need to unrotate the character and update its global transformation so its upright relative to your screen and falls toward {0, -1, 0}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

---

About the transformations, the `xform` method of Godot 3 has been replaced with the `*` operator. So you multiply the transform together to compose them, or you multiply a transform and a vector to transform it.

---

I'm not sure exactly how you want to control it, but here are some considerations:

- There is a default gravity in project settings, which you might want to change. But you can have dynamic gravity by overriding it with `Area3D`s. If you need to read the gravity that applies where the body is, use: `PhysicsServer3D.body_get_direct_state(get_rid()).total_gravity`.
- The `CharacterBody3D` has an `up_direction` defined in the global basis, which is used to decide what is floor, wall, or ceiling. Thus, you will likely want to change it dynamically.
- It is common - beyond beginner code - to make the control relative to the `Camera3D`. For example "right" will not be towards global positive X, but towards positive X of the `Camera3D`. If you need a reference to the `Camera3D`, you can get it with `get_viewport().get_camera_3d()`.
- The `velocity` of the `CharacterBody3D` is in the global basis.